# Is it possible to solve $\frac{z}{y}=\left(1-{xca}\right)\left(1-{xcb}\right)(1-x)^{n}$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

$$\frac{z}{y}=\left(1-{xca}\right)\left(1-{xcb}\right)(1-x)^{n}$$

Can we solve this equation for $x$ such that, in the new equation we have, $x$ is the dependent variable, and $n$ is the independent variable, $c$, $a$, $b$, $y$, $z$ are all constants.

I have found it impossible to isolate $x$ on one side. I hope someone can help.

Comment: for arbitrary $n$ a closed-form expression will not be forthcoming

Answer (score 1):

Start by simplifying the notation. Let $A = 1-\frac{m_1}a, B = 1-\frac{m_2}b, C = \frac{m_1m_2z}{aby}, k = n-2$ and $t = 1-x$. After multiplying through by $\frac{m_1m_2}{ab}$, the problem becomes solving $$(t-A)(t-B)t^k = C$$
If $C = 0$, we would be in luck. The solutions would be $t = A, t = B, t = 0$, or $x = 1-A, x = 1-B, x = 1$.

Alas, when $C \ne 0$, it is not so easy. You have a polynomial equation of degree $n = k+2$ in $t$. There is a famous result that there is no closed form solution for $t$ involving just addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and the taking of roots. You can come up with closed form solutions using esoteric functions, but those esoteric functions are merely a mathematical relabeling of the problem. They offer no new insight into it, and do not give easier methods of calculating $t$.

So what can we do? If your need is theoretical, just the existence of a solution is usually enough, without having some specific formula for calculating it. If your need is practical, finding a numeric value for a specific set of parameter values, then there are very good means of approximating the answer to any accuracy. (And if you think you need an exact value, not an approximation - as many mathematical neophytes often think - you are very much mistaken. Any formula would have given you an approximate value only. It is impossible to ever have an exact value of an irrational number.)

The case for $k = 0$ is just a quadratic equation that is solvable with the quadratic formula Using a little calculus (yes, I see the precalculus tag, but I'll take care of the calculus and you will just have to trust that what I tell you from it is accurate), for $k > 0$ the turning points of the polynomial $P(t) = (t-A)(t-B)t^k - C$ are at the solutions to the equation $$t^{k-1}[t(t - B) + t(t - A) + k(t-A)(t-B)] = 0$$
which are

- $r_0 = 0$ for $k > 1$ only,
- $r_1 = \dfrac{(k+1)(A+B) - \sqrt{(k+1)^2(A+B)^2 - 4(k+2)kAB}}{2k+4}$,
- $r_2 = \dfrac{(k+1)(A+B) + \sqrt{(k+1)^2(A+B)^2 - 4(k+2)kAB}}{2k+4}$.

When $k$ is even, all three will be turning points. These turning points divide the real line into four intervals, one from $-\infty$ to the lowest root, the next from the lowest root to the middle root, and so on. When $k$ is odd, $r_0$ will not be a turning point. Instead the curve will level off there, but then continue on in the same direction, much like $y = x^3$ does around $x = 0$. So for odd $k, P(t)$ has only two turning poimts at $r_1, r_2$. These divide the real line into three intervals.

Let $y_0 = P(r_0) = P(0) = -C, y_1 = P(r_1), y_2 = P(r_2)$. For $k$ even,

- if all three $y$ values are $< 0$, the equation $P(t) = 0$ will have two roots, one below the lowest turning point, and the other above the greatest turning point.
- If two of the $y$ values is $< 0$, the equation will have four roots, one in each of the intervals defined by the turning points.
- If one of the $y$ values is $<0$, the equation will have two roots, one in each of the intervals on either side of the negative turning point.
- If none of the $y$ values is $\le 0$, then the equation has no real roots.

For $k$ odd, ignore $y_0$, and consider only $y_1,y_2$.

- If both $y$ values are $< 0$, the equation has a single root, greater than the larger of $r_1, r_2$.
- If one $y$ value is negative and the other positive, the equation has three roots, one in each of the intervals.
- If neither $y$ value is $\le 0$, the equation has a single root, less than the lower of $r_1, r_2$.

How can you find the roots? For each interval where a root resides per the conditions above, pick an arbitrary point $t_0$ in the interval (not the end points). Then for each $i$, calculate
$$t_{i+1} = t_i - \dfrac{(t_i-A)(t_i-B)t_i^k - C}{t_i^{k-1}[t_i(2t_i - A - B) + k(t_i-A)(t_i-B)]}$$
The $t_i$ will converge to the root of the equation in that interval, and will do so very quickly. Keep calculating new $t_i$ until the difference between consecutive values is below the level of tolerance your application needs. Use the last value as your root.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul Sinclair for your answer, after we get the equation p(t)=(t-A)(t-B)t^k,  I suppose you took its derivative and put it equal to 0, so we get the points where slope of the function is zero. why do we need relative Maxima and minimas, how do we get the equations for r0, r1, r2, and I didn't get the thing about k being even or odd, and in the end you gave an equation for ti+1, what approximation method is this, I think I need to study all of this in depth, which field and topic of maths cover this.

Comment: Paul at the end did you use Newton's method of approximation?

Comment: You put a pre-calculus tag on the question, thus I did not try to explain the calculus involved and only talked about the results. Yes, the recursion formula is Newton's method. The identification of the turning points was to determine in which intervals should you use Newton's method to find a root. This is highly important. If you search for a root in the wrong place, it doesn't work. For example, when all the turning points have positive $y$-value, you will just be wasting your time using Newton's method to find a root,as there is no root to find, and the method will not converge.

Comment: The formulas for $r_0, r_1, r_2$ are obtained by setting the derivative to $0$. These three roots are the only ones the derivative has. Note that the derivative is $t^{k-1}$ times a quadratic, so either $t^{k-1}=0$ or the quadratic $=0$, which gives the three solutions. I discuss even and odd values of $k$ separately because even and odd degree polynomials behave differently, as I described. For example, odd degree polynomials always have at least one real root. Even degree polynomials can have no real roots at all.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul for your help, bcz of you now I'm thinking in a different direction, I want to study all of this in depth, even odd values of k, y- values and r- equation ect in depth, what should I do, does Newton's method of approximation cover all of this, would you be able to maybe recommend a book.

Comment: This is all basic calculus knowledge. Any differentiable function whose derivative has isolated zeros will be either increasing or decreasing in the intervals determined by its turning points. It can have at most one root in each. If two adjacent turning points are on opposite sides of the $x$-axis, there is a root between them by the intermediate value theorem. If they are both on the same side of the axis, then there is no root. Newton's method just discusses the iteration process. Where to look is not usually covered in it. What is important is it is not guaranteed to find a root.

Comment: With a general function, it is possible for it to flit back and forth without settling down. But polynomials are well-behaved, so as long as you stay away from zeros of the derivative (turning point or not) - which can send the next iterate way off into another region - and there is a root in the interval where you start out, Newton's method will converge to that root.